# Hexrays - Enhance decompilation of "pre-multiplied" array indices?

Tags: ida, x86, hexrays, array

For this x86 (Watcom 1997) assembly that loops over an array, Hexrays yields the following pseudo code:

```
lea     eax, ds:0[ecx*4]
add     eax, ecx
shl     eax, 3
mov     [esp+310h+iMulSize], eax

mov     edx, [esp+310h+iMulSize]
mov     eax, [esi+14h]
add     edx, eax
mov     eax, [esp+310h+v3Normal.x]
mov     [edx], eax

mov     edx, [esp+310h+iMulSize]
mov     eax, [esi+14h]
add     edx, eax
mov     eax, [esp+310h+v3Normal.y]
mov     [edx+4], eax

mov     ebx, [esp+310h+iMulSize]
mov     edx, [esi+14h]
add     edx, ebx
mov     eax, [esp+310h+v3Normal.z]
mov     [edx+8], eax
```

```c
iMulSize = sizeof(Tri) * i; // sizeof(Tri) = 0x28

pObject->paTris[i].v3Normal.x = v3Normal.x; // paTris at 0x14 in pObject
*(int *)((char *)&pObject->paTris->v3Normal.y + iMulSize) = v3Normal.y;
*(int *)((char *)&pObject->paTris->v3Normal.z + iMulSize) = v3Normal.z;
```

While easy to understand here, it leads to quite unreadable pseudo code in more complicated parts which also "pre-multiply" array indices by element size.

I tried to apply [shifted pointers](https://hex-rays.com/blog/igors-tip-of-the-week-54-shifted-pointers/) functionality, but don't know how for array indices. **Is there a way I can enhance the output to become more readable as below?** As seen in this 1998 version of the executable (which is not of analysis interest):

```c
pObject->paTris[i].v3Normal.x = v3Normal.x;
pObject->paTris[i].v3Normal.y = v3Normal.y;
pObject->paTris[i].v3Normal.z = v3Normal.z;
```

```
imul    eax, [ebp+i], 28h
mov     edx, [ebp+pObject]
mov     edx, [edx+14h]
add     edx, eax
mov     eax, [ebp+v3Normal.x]
mov     [edx], eax

imul    edx, [ebp+i], 28h
mov     eax, [ebp+pObject]
mov     eax, [eax+14h]
add     edx, eax
mov     eax, [ebp+v3Normal.y]
mov     [edx+4], eax

imul    edx, [ebp+i], 28h
mov     eax, [ebp+pObject]
mov     eax, [eax+14h]
add     edx, eax
mov     eax, [ebp+v3Normal.z]
mov     [edx+8], eax
```

Comment: Which version of Hex-Rays? They've made changes to this part over the years.

Comment: @RolfRolles I'm still on 7.6 SP1 sadly.

Comment: do you have a link to the binary?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky I uploaded both binaries (as they're found in publicly available patches anyway) at https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApLbv3xVffjriVPTQ6CRIAqYFHUg . As mentioned, the older exe "premultiplies" a lot while the newer doesn't; sampled array access is at 004A6EA9 (older) / 004C56DE (newer) - though maybe a bit long and needing the structs for a recognizable decompile (I can search for simpler examples if required). The older executable also seemingly orders instructions unusually.